# My speakers making humming noise and can't seem to find a solution for fixing them

Tags: audio, speakers, noise

Hello i have MicroLab Solo 1 speakers that i just bought and they are making a buzzing/humming noise when they are just turned on and no cables are plugged in just the AC one. I have tried different outlets but nothing seems to work. 
I have searched for an answer but haven't found one.

So can someone please help me with some kind of an answer that may work solving this.

Thank you.

Comment: How loud is the sound? Very softly or moderately loud?

Comment: Its softly but you can hear it very clear when room is quiet

Comment: What happens if you plug in the audio cable at both ends? Its likely receiving the noise from no cable being plugged in and thus acts like an antenna.

Comment: Already did that still i am having the buzzing sound even if i play something, you can hear it in the background

Comment: You may want to return the speakers to the shop, given that its a new one. Might be a hardware defect.

Comment: Relevant: [Speaker hum, power supply or motherboard?](//superuser.com/q/1152212), [Mains hum in speakers after plugging in a cable](//superuser.com/q/970774), [Desktop PC Speakers are Humming/Buzzing](//superuser.com/q/234913)

Comment: Thanks for the comment checked all of them and tried but still nothing. I think i will take them back and see what they say at the store thank you!